# The methods method1 and method2 use the same SOAPAction

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I'm implementing a webservice based on a wsdl that is provided by another company. I need to implement a webservice-stub for testing purposes. So I used wsdl.exe to generate the client and serverside interfaces and implemented them. When I do a webservice call I get an exception saying The methods method1 and method2 use the same SOAPAction ''. Looking at the wsdl shows that the two methods do not provide a soapaction

```
<operation name="method1">
   <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
...
</operation>
<operation name="method2">
   <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
...
</operation>
```

The exception is thrown when I connect the client to the Webservice-stub not when I connect to the real webservice.

Is there a way to configure / implement the webservice-stub to ignore the soapAction-Header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the RoutingStyle property of the [SoapDocumentServiceAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapdocumentserviceattribute.routingstyle.aspx) to [SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapserviceroutingstyle.aspx).

```
[SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle=SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement, ...)]
public class ServiceNameHere : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
   ...
}
```